# CircleShape crashing program when defined as an instance variable

Tags: c++, sfml

I am encountering a perplexing issue in my SFML game development where my program crashes instantly during runtime when I add a `CircleShape` as an instance variable in my Tile.h file. The crash occurs even before my game window is loaded.

Here is the relevant section of my Tile.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Tile{
private:
    sf::IntRect rect;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    int width;
    int x;
    int y;
    sf::CircleShape hexagon; // The problematic line causing the crash
public:
    Tile(int x, int y, int width, sf::Texture& texture);
    Tile();
    int getX();
    int getY();
    int getWidth();
    void setX(int x);
    void setY(int y);
    void setWidth(int w);
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
};
```

The crash persists whether or not I initialize the hexagon instance in the constructors. Strangely, the program runs successfully if I remove the instance variable declaration in Tile.h and instead initialize it within the constructors like this:

```
Tile::Tile(int x, int y, int width, sf::Texture& texture) : x(x), y(y), width(width), rect(x, y, width, width), sprite(texture){
    sf::CircleShape hexagon = sf::CircleShape(20, 6);
    sprite.setScale((double)width / (double)texture.getSize().x, (double)width / (double)texture.getSize().y);
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}

Tile::Tile() : x(0), y(0), width(1) {
    sf::CircleShape hexagon = sf::CircleShape(20, 6);
}
```

This leads me to believe that the inclusion of the instance variable in Tile.h is the root cause of the error. I plan to use the hexagon for collision detection and have omitted its drawing for now.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and understand why the `CircleShape` instance is causing the program to crash. Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any particular error message from the crash, or when hooking a debugger and stepping through the start-up code?

Comment: The code you've posted has a local `sf::CircleShape` variable within the constructor, this obviously does nothing so it's unclear what your code is supposed to do. Can you post the actual code that crashes? Or, better, a minimum viable example showing the crash.